# how the ram is used while html page is loaded by browser

Tags: html

Well I don't know what is the role of ram while any page that is coming from server is loaded by browser

So ultimately I want know how ram is used when we open any website in our browser.

Comment: On the server, or on the client?

Comment: Depends on the browser, but generally to store any memory required. The HTML may be written to a temp file and and kept there during viewing.

Comment: I thinks this question belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider browser as a software which receives an input from the Server & User.

HTML is the input from the server. The browser has to work on it & produce an output. The output is the page that the user sees.

RAM is the primary memory for the browser. It totally depends on the browser on how much of the memory, it needs to render the page for the user.

And how judiciously a browser manages the memory is what everyone refers to the browser performance.

Hope you get a rough idea...

[image]

The Megabytes shown to be used by the browsers above, is the RAM used to render a page by them.

Comment: great. Then you could perhaps mark the green tick as helpful :)